# Is possible for fluent-ffmpeg to take WebRTC stream as input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, fluent-ffmpeg, mediastream

I am exploring fluent-ffmpeg and saw that in the Shell version (ffmpeg) [is possible to use a RTMP streaming as parameter and take a frame-by-frame collection](http://thewowza.guru/take-a-screenshot-of-a-live-stream-via-ffmpeg/)

I wanted to know if that is possible in fluent-ffmpeg and if it can be made with a WebRTC MediaStream instead of a RTMP url

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean taking snapshots from the streaming rtmp server

Comment: Yes, just with media stream, media recorder and ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Nope, FFMPEG doesn't supports WebRTC for now.
You can use GStreamer, it supports WebRTC. But there is no node.js bindings for GStreamer for now.